# Modifying user.username in Session With PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a form that allows people to update their profile information, which is populated with data from `req.user` via PassportJS.

The problem is that whenever I update the value that corresponds to `user.username` I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
```

From line 6 in this snippet of code:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas", function(e, db){
  if (e) {return next(e);}
  var col = db.collection("users");
  col.findOne({"username": id}, function(err, user){
    done(err, {"id": user._id, "username": id, "activeEmail": user.activeEmail, "name": user.name, "password": user.password, "formulas": user.formulas});
    });
  });
});
```

I'm assuming it's because in `serializeUser` I'm using `user.username` to load it into session like so:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.username);
});
```

Does anyone know how to go about getting around this or is it an intractable issue with Passport?

The code I have that does the update generically looks like this:

```
router.post('/update-profile', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var db = req.db.collection('users');

    db.updateOne({"username": username}, {
      $set: {
          "name": name,
          "username": username,
        }
      }, function(err, r) {
         assert.equal(null, err);
         assert.equal(null, r.matchedCount);
      }
    });
    res.render('profile', {
      user: req.user
    });
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

Per comment request, the error message from `findOne` in `serializeUser` is `null` when it's called, so it's not the query that's the problem.

Comment: try checking the error inside `col.findone` before calling `done`. `if(err) console.log(err)`. may be you will get to know why `user` is `null`

Comment: I did this and the error message was `null`.

Comment: Just because there isn't an error doesn't mean that it found a user.

Comment: I know it didn't find a user, because `req.user` returns a value of `null` as well.  I'm just not sure exactly why this only happens when I update the value that corresponds to `user.username` and nowhere else.

Comment: Look. It seems you are putting the `user.username` in the session. So when you change it in the database, the two values will be different. So the query will return null. You should use the `user._id` to put in the session. I believe it is the error.

Comment: I think you HAVE to use `user.username` in Passport.  It says so in the documentation.  I've tried using `user._id` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `username` is changeable value, you should not use it as session cookie key.

I strongly recommend using `user._id` instead as it is unchanged value, so that server still "know" the current user **even if username has been changed**. Check official [**http://passportjs.org/docs**](http://passportjs.org/docs), they are also using `id` as session cookie key.

Btw, even if you are using `username`, you should do NULL check for `passport.deserializeUser()`:

```
col.findOne({"username": id}, function(err, user){
    if (user) {
        done(err, {"id": user._id, "username": id, "activeEmail": user.activeEmail, "name": user.name, "password": user.password, "formulas": user.formulas});
    } else {
        done(new Error('User not found'));
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried using `user._id` in `serializeUser` but I get an error message that says `failed to serialize user into session`.

Comment: Yes.  `done(null, user._id)` returns that message.  I believe it has something to do with how Passport is setup, but right now I can't connect the dots.

Comment: I think you will want to use `col.findOne({"_id": id}` also. About the `failed to serialize user into session` issue, try `console.log(user._id)` to check its value.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code on passport deserialize funtion. You didn't checked, user is available or not. So when no user found, You got that error>

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas", function(e, db){
  if (e) {return next(e);}
  var col = db.collection("users");
  col.findOne({"username": id}, function(err, user){
    if (err){
        done(new Error('No user found on db'));
    }else if (user){
         done(err, {"id": user._id, "username": id, "activeEmail": user.activeEmail, "name": user.name, "password": user.password, "formulas": user.formulas});
    });
    }
  });
});
```